# Boolean map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have boolean position map for example

`var position={"isAdmin":true,"isisPleb":false}`

I wanna add all true position another list. how can I do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with basic for loop.

```
List<String> getPosition(Map newMap) {
  List<String> positions = [];
  for (var i in newMap.entries) {
    if (i.value) {
      positions.add(i.key);
    }
  }
  return positions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also simple way:

```
List listPosition = [];
position.forEach((key, value) {
    if(value==true) listPosition.add(key);
});
```